# Linq - getting a value that is between a lower limit and upper limit

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Fees (linq to sql entity- if relevant) - Upper Fee, Lower Fee (both are decimal values). I am passing in a `property value` - say 90000 and I want to check if this `property` value **best** matches *one* (or *first* value out of many) from the list of fees.

The fees could be something like...

**(lower fee - upper fee)**

```
0 - 50000
50001 - 75000
75001 - 90000
90001 - 140000
190000 - 500000
```

Out of these values, 90000 is best matched for something like *75001 - 90000 band*, so I want to pull out that **FeeDetail** entity. I dont really know what operator to use, any help is appreciated, my code so far is...

```
    [Test]
    public void GetFeeRange()
   {
        const int id = 44;
        var propValue = 90000;

        //get a specific fee entity, then get the range of fee details...
        var recommendedFees = RepoSession.All<Fee>()
            .Where(x =>
                   x.ClientSurveyTypeID == id)
            .GroupJoin(_readOnlySession.All<FeeDetail>(),
                       x => x.FeeID,
                       y => y.FeeID,
                       (x, y) => new
                                     {
                                         FeeDetail = y.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                     })
            .Select(x => x.FeeDetail)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        Assert.IsNotNull(recommendedFees);

       //order fees by lowest fee - *the bit I am stuck on*
        var bestMatch = recommendedFees.OrderBy(x => x.Lower)
            .TakeWhile(x => propValue >= x.Lower || propValue <= x.Upper)
            .FirstOrDefault();



    }
```

Question- how would I perform the range checks? What operator of linq do I need? Not sure if I should perform a takewhile then, get the best fee from that range?

NOTE: the fees could very easily be...

**(lower fee - upper fee)**

```
0 - 50000
50001 - 75000
95001 - 140000
190000 - 500000
```

If a best match is found, pull that out *OR* get the closest match... maybe I can show a list of available matches if one is not (near enough) an exact match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a simple `.Where` should be fine:

```
var bestMatch = recommendedFees
              .Where(x => propValue >= x.Lower && propValue <= x.Upper)
              .OrderBy(x => x.Lower)                  
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1, but the OR operator should be replaced with an AND. `.Where(x => propValue >= x.Lower && propValue <= x.Upper)`

Comment: @PaulSasik Yeah, spotted that after I posted and changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like...

```
recommendedFees.Where(x => x.upperFee >= theFee).OrderByDescending(x => x.upperFee).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That `Take(1)` part is redundant, due to the deferred execution of LINQ queries.

Comment: Need to have a look at that as some time ago when using First/FirstOrDefault I was getting Exceptions that 'sequence contains more than 1 element' so its a bit of a habit to use Take(1)

Comment: That exception occurs when using `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` on an `IEnumerable<T>` with more than one element; afaik the `FirstOrDefault` method did never throw anything except when it's `source` was `null`.

Comment: I like this method, because often sliding scales are stored only with one boundary, e.g. the lower boundary. The upper boundary is implied. This caters for that use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myfee = 90000;
var myFoundFeeRange = (from feeRange in feeRanges 
          where feeRange.lowerfee <= myfee && myfee <= feeRange.upperfee 
          select feeRange ).First()
```

This will do a simple check that the fee is within the boundary. And return the matching boundary

Comment: You will have to check for `<=` instead of `<` or the OP's example won't match anything.