# Find a value between a List's upper and lower limits

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently calculating tax rate by the following way

```
int testValue = 180000;

List<TaxBracket> taxes = new List<TaxBracket>();
taxes.Add(new TaxBracket(18199, 0)); //0 to 18199
taxes.Add(new TaxBracket(36999, 19)); //18200 to 36999
taxes.Add(new TaxBracket(79999, Convert.ToDecimal(32.50D))); //37000 to 79999
taxes.Add(new TaxBracket(179999, 37)); //80000 to 179999 
taxes.Add(new TaxBracket(180000, 47)); //180000

decimal result = taxes[taxes.Count-1].Value;

for (int i = 0; i < taxes.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        if (testValue < taxes[i].Limit)
            result = 0;
    }

    if (i > 0)
    {
        if (testValue < taxes[i].Limit && testValue > taxes[i - 1].Limit) 
        {
            result = taxes[i].Value;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Is there any alternate in LINQ to do this instead of using this old-school approach? Looks pretty close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017803/linq-getting-a-value-that-is-between-a-lower-limit-and-upper-limit) but a bit different.

Comment: Could you please tell me the logic : how `TaxBracket(36999, 19));` will be `18200 to 36999`, `18200 ` comes from where?

Comment: @un-lucky - each item in the collection is the top number of the range. So item 0 is for all the values until the limit - which is 18199

Comment: Try following solution which will return null if value is greater than table values :             decimal? result = taxes.Where(x => testValue < x.Limit).Select(x => x.Value).LastOrDefault();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is what you want:

```
var result = taxes.OrderBy(item => item.Limit)
                  .SkipWhile(item => item.Limit < testValue)
                  .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

It will order your collection from smallest `Limit` to largest and then will `Skip` until it reaches a `Limit` that is equal or greater than your `testValue`. Because collection is ordered then the `FirstOrDefault` and it's value.

Or:

```
var result = taxes.Where(item => item.Limit >= testValue )
                  .OrderBy(item => item.Limit)
                  .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

This way looks at the problem from a different direction. Take only the items that are equal or to `testValue` and then order them ant take the first.

Answer (score 3):

As a *Linq alternative* I suggest using *binary search*, providing that `taxes` is sorted:

```
int index = taxes.BinarySearch(
  new TaxBracket(testValue, -1), // -1: this parameter is ignored
  Comparer<TaxBracket>.Create((left, right) => left.Limit.CompareTo(right.Limit)));

if (index < 0)
  index = ~index - 1; // in between of two indexes

var result = taxes[index].Value;
```

Binary search can be useful when you work with *long* list (the algorithm ensures `O(log(N))` complexity, when *Linq* provides `O(N)` one); but when `taxes` is small, *Linq* `SkipWhile` (see Gilad Green's answer) is *more readable*

Comment: Is this somehow better compared to approach suggested by @Gilad Green?

Comment: @3615 - I'd say that on smaller collections the performance won't really matter but on large ones this is more efficient :)

Comment: @Dmitry - Nice approach

Comment: @3615: *Binary search* is better when working with long lists (better time complexity - `O(log(N))` v. `O(N)`); it's an *aletrnative to Linq* (as it's put in the question). The main drawback - it's far *less readable*.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications!

Comment: @Gilad Green: you're quite right, it's a *readability* that's matter in the context and your *Linq* approach is preferrable. All I wanted was just to show the *alternative* to Linq.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko First, congrats for the answer. But contrary to your previous comment, I think this method is preferable and Linq is just a (quick and dirty) alternative. The only annoying thing is the lack of standard `BinarySearchBy<T, TKey>` to avoid creating fake object and comparison comparer.

Comment: I love your alternative. It's smart and in the case of performance issues then it is better to go that way - the only problem is that it has to assume it is ordered - if you need to order it first then it isn't more efficient

Comment: I agree this method is possibly better for very long sequences, but its requirement of creating a dummy search element will cause huge overhead compared to a simple linear search for sequences that are not very long. Of course, that could be avoided by writing a binary search extension for lists that allows the search element to be specified (I use such an extension myself).

Comment: @Gilad Green: usually, sorting is not a big problem: `taxes` should be sorted just once (on loading, on first call etc)

Comment: Incidentally, I think this will result in `index` being -1 if the search value is between 0 and 18198

Comment: @Matthew Watson: I've tried to emulate and in case value is in between 0 and 18198, I've got `index == -2` which has been converted to `0` by `if (index < 0) index = ~index - 1;`

Comment: Look at my where solution above.